# APA 6th article style and referencing

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I need to prepare a manuscript according to APA 6th style. I tried using the apa6 class and biblatex for document style and references respectively. The citations within the contents are not coming out properly, and the bibliography is not printed (despite using the \printbibliography command). Please advise what is wrong. My code is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,biblatex]{apa6}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{soccer.bib}
 @book{kuper2012,
  title={Soccernomics: Why England Loses, why Spain, Germany, and Brazil win, and why the US, Japan, Australia, Turkey - and even Iraq - are destined to become the kings of the world's most popular sport},
  author={Kuper, Simon and Szymanski, Stefan},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Nation Books, New York}
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{soccer.bib}

\begin{document}
Soccer is one of the most popular sports in the world \parencite{kuper2012}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE works perfectly fine here. You have to run Biber on your document. Let's say your file is called called `document.tex`, then you would have to run `pdflatex document`, `biber document`, `pdflatex document`, `pdflatex document`. Please see [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for a first guess what's wrong. Did you run Biber? What do the `.log` and `.blg` files say?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I experience no problems generating the expected output. Did you run LaTeX, biber, and LaTeX once more?

Comment: Hey @moewe and Mico, I apologize for not coming back here to check the answers for my question. I think I switched to using natbib, and solved my problem. However, the above posted MWE doesn't give an output for me, despite using the sequences of running that both of you suggested. When I run, I get the message:

Comment: When I run the MWE, I get the message: Process started: biber.exe "document"

INFO - This is Biber 2.5
INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.2, expected version 3.1.
This means that your biber (2.5) and biblatex (3.6) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: As the error says: Your versions of `biblatex` and Biber don't match. Run an update (via `tlmgr` on TeX live and both Updaters - Admin and User - on MikTeX). With `biblatex` version 3.6 you need to use Biber 2.6.